# Permutation Representation in groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This may sound like a very basic question but it's confusing me a lot?

I.N. Herstein defines a isomorphism from group $G$ to a subgroup of $S_n$ by using $\tau_g$ as $x\tau_g=xg$. Then it goes on to prove $\tau_{g_1g_2}=\tau_{g_1}\tau_{g_2}$.

> $x\tau_{g_1g_2}=xg_1g_2=(x\tau_{g_1})g_2=(x\tau_{g_1})\tau_{g_2}$.

My question is suppose I use a different notation like $\tau_gx=xg$. The result comes out to be $\tau_{g_1g_2}=\tau_{g_2}\tau_{g_1}$.

> $\tau_{g_1g_2}x=xg_1g_2=(\tau_{g_1}x)g_2=\tau_{g_2}\tau_{g_1}x$.

Since it's just a matter of notation shouldn't these two results be equal. Am I missing something? Should we use second representation only for $\tau_gx=gx$?

Comment: It is a matter of notation, but they should still be different.  Multiplying on the right is different from multiplying on the left.  You should also expect a difference if you write function arguments as $xf$ as opposed to $f(x)$.

Comment: Multiplication on right is different and left is different I get that. My point was while proving G isomorphic to subgroup of $S_n$.

Comment: I don't understand the question then.  Both are valid and give you different isomorphisms with a subgroup of $S_n$.

Comment: Basically my question was we can't use second $\tau$ notation with right multiplication?

Comment: Yes, you can.  You still get an isomorphism with a subgroup of $S_n$.  This is called the right regular representation.  Your isomorphism then maps $g \in G$ to $\tau_{g^{-1}}$.

Comment: How, like I mentioned if we define $phi(g)=\tau_g$ and $\tau_gx=xg$ then  $phi(g_1g_2)=\tau_{g_2}\tau_{g_1}$.

Comment: Because you check it.  $\phi(gh) = \tau_{(gh)^{-1}} = \tau_{h^{-1}g^{-1}} = \tau_{g^{-1}}\tau_{h^{-1}} = \phi(g)\phi(h)$.

Comment: Ok this makes sense, we just had to modify our definition little bit.Thanks